# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - Images not loading from database ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a AdRotator that is bind with a SQLDatasource to read out the data. Unfortunately, it is unable to read out the image on my page.

I have a function at the Admin page where they will be able to upload images and it is displayed in the Gridview. But not sure what's happening on the user side. I checked my "File Explorer" and Advertisement_Banner.dbo and images are successfully updated.

Can anyone help me with this?

**User Page**

```
        <center><asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server" Target="_blank" Width="100%" Height="50%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ImageUrlField='' /></center>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Advertisement_Banners]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Admin Page**

**Uploading Images**
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string filextn = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

```
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            lblmessage.Text = "Please make sure you submit the correct advertisement banner";
        }
        else
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)
            {

                if (filextn.ToLower() != ".jpg" && filextn.ToLower() != ".png")
                {
                    Label10.Text = "Only .jpg and .png files are accepted";
                }
                else
                {

                    //This portion is for storing files in folder
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedfile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        string userPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images");
                        if (!Directory.Exists(userPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(userPath);
                        }
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
                        postedfile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(userPath, filename));

                        lblmessage.Text = "Your image has been successfully submitted.";


                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
                        {

                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveAdBanner", con);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"SFC_Doc_ID", Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text));

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"NavigateUrl", TextBox1.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"AlternateText", TextBox2.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Keyword", TextBox3.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Impressions", TextBox4.Text);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageUrl", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "~/Images/" + postedfile.FileName;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(postedfile.FileName);

                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();

                            //Disable Submit Button After Submission
                            Button1.Enabled = false;

                            ShowBanners();


                        }



                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Screenshot of error (User side)
[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aymye.png)
[Image failed to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BXSr.png)

Comment: You need to show your controller and actions.

Comment: Hi @Sergey, I do not have any controller. The above is what I have